# How to set multiple values on a tag field

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I want to be able to set a string array of ID's separated by commas from the backend on a tag field so that records in the store with the equivalent  ID are pre-selected.

The delimiter is set to ',' by default so that shouldn't be a problem.

I have tried something like

```
me.formReference.getForm().findField('tagfield').setValue("1, 2");
```

But only the associated record with '1' is selected and '2' is not.

(Also working with version 6.5)

Comment: The space probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: You're kidding me! That was the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: I can also recommend `setValue([1,2])`. In that case, the space doesn't matter ;-)